# Remove some hooked functions based on virtual products in WooCommerce Checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, hook-woocommerce

I want to remove some information on checkout page when there is only virtual products in cart.

The following is removing what I want on checkout page:

```
  remove_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_terms_and_conditions', 'wc_checkout_privacy_policy_text', 20 );
  remove_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_terms_and_conditions', 'wc_terms_and_conditions_page_content', 30 );
  remove_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_terms_and_conditions', 'woocontracts_terms_fields', );
  remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'woocommerce_checkout_coupon_form', 10 );
  remove_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_review', 'woocommerce_order_review', 10 );
  remove_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_after_terms_and_conditions', 'woocontracts_checkout_additional_checkboxes', 10 );
  remove_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', 'woocontracts_checkout_field_process', 10 );
```

how to make the same when there is only virtual products in cart?

I Tried the following:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_after_terms_and_conditions' , 'bbloomer_simplify_checkout_virtualab' );
 
function bbloomer_simplify_checkout_virtualab( $fields ) {
    
   $only_virtual = true;
    
   foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
      // Check if there are non-virtual products
      if ( ! $cart_item['data']->is_virtual() ) $only_virtual = false;   
   }
     
    if( $only_virtual ) {
                

  remove_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_terms_and_conditions', 'wc_checkout_privacy_policy_text', 20 );
  remove_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_terms_and_conditions', 'wc_terms_and_conditions_page_content', 30 );
  remove_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_terms_and_conditions', 'woocontracts_terms_fields', );
  remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'woocommerce_checkout_coupon_form', 10 );
  remove_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_review', 'woocommerce_order_review', 10 );
        
return $fields;
}
     
     return $fields;
}
```

But it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update 2** - The right hook to use in this case is `woocommerce_checkout_init` action hook:

```
// Custom conditional function that checks if there is only virtual items in cart
function has_only_virtual_items_in_cart(){
    $only_virtual = true;

    // Check if there are non-virtual items in cart
    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        if ( ! $cart_item['data']->is_virtual() ) {
            $only_virtual = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return $only_virtual;
}

// Unhook some functions conditionally
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_init', 'simplify_checkout_for_virtual_items_only' );
function simplify_checkout_for_virtual_items_only() {
    if( has_only_virtual_items_in_cart() ) {
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'woocommerce_checkout_coupon_form', 10 );
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_review', 'woocommerce_order_review', 10 );
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_terms_and_conditions', 'wc_checkout_privacy_policy_text', 20 );
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_terms_and_conditions', 'wc_terms_and_conditions_page_content', 30 );
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_terms_and_conditions', 'woocontracts_terms_fields' ); // <== missing priority
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_after_terms_and_conditions', 'woocontracts_checkout_additional_checkboxes', 10 );
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

> Then you can reuse the custom contional function `has_only_virtual_items_in_cart()` inside `woocontracts_checkout_field_process()` function hooked in `woocommerce_checkout_process` hook.

Comment: Ok found the right hook !!! after many different attempts… This will solve the issue completely… could you please delete / remove old comments as they are not needed now, thank you.

Comment: last things   with this code i want to remove view cart message. How can i do this. ?

Comment: i am new at stackoverflow sory. your suggettion is workin now wonderfull. last things how can i remove wiev cart message in checkout page ?

Comment: @musabaltaci Which cart message?… I don't see any… Is better to ask a new question, explaining the problem (trying to search before if you find some other questions/answers that can help).